# How to extract bitcoin address only from a block in the blockchain

Tags: php, json, bitcoin

I'm trying to extract the bitcoin address from the blockchain. To be more specific if you go to this link https://blockchain.info/btc/block/1 you would see that the bitcoin address on that block is "12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX"

What is the best way to extract that details using PHP/Json ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

take a look at blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api

you got everything there.

Comment: thank you, it's exactly what i needed

Answer (score -1):

blockchain.info has an API to get block details.

[blockchain.info API](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api)

Using `https://blockchain.info/block-height/$block_height` endpoint, you can pass `$block_height` as block number that you need.

Then by simple script like below, you can extract the addresses.

```
<?php

$blockTxs = getBlockTxs(1);

foreach ($blockTxs as $tx) {
    foreach ($tx->out as $out)
    {
        var_dump($out->addr);
    }
}


function getBlockTxs($height) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://blockchain.info/block-height/' . $height,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'GET',
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    return (json_decode($response))->blocks[0]->tx;
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly great solution, thank you so much

Comment: Just a question, in your code line `8 var_dump($out->addr);` can we save it to a txt file?

Comment: yes, use `file_put_contents` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: `file_put_contents(($file, $out->addr) . "\n" , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\laragon\www\blockchain\test.php on line 10 Do you see something not correct?

Comment: Thank you i figured it out `file_put_contents($file, $out->addr . "\n" , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`